# Strange behaviour of UTF8 GetBytes() with non-ascii symbols

Tags: c#, utf-8, stream, httpwebrequest

Can anyone see the difference between this two blocks of code?

1:

```
Byte[] arInput = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput);
```

2:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
Byte[] arInput = UTF8.GetBytes(sInput);
```

Afterwards I write arInput in System.IO.Stream, and send Stream in HttpWebRequest to remote server.

For some reason when I pass non-ascii characters in sInput, server returns 500 error when I use first bunch of code, but it works fine with second one. I tried to pass true and false to UTF8Encoding() constructor, but nothing changed.

Comment: What are you asking? What's different between the code samples or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `Encoding.UTF8` and `new UTF8Encoding()` is that the former has the BOM enabled, but that **only** matters if `GetPreamble()` is called - so when calling `GetBytes()`, there is exactly no difference.

I would suggest you update with example input and output from both encodings.

Example:

```
Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
string s = "abc";
Console.WriteLine("new UTF8Encoding(), preamble: {0}",
    BitConverter.ToString(enc.GetPreamble()));
Console.WriteLine("new UTF8Encoding(), payload: {0}",
    BitConverter.ToString(enc.GetBytes(s)));
enc = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("Encoding.UTF8, preamble: {0}",
    BitConverter.ToString(enc.GetPreamble()));
Console.WriteLine("Encoding.UTF8, payload: {0}",
    BitConverter.ToString(enc.GetBytes(s)));
```

which writes:

```
new UTF8Encoding(), preamble:
new UTF8Encoding(), payload: 61-62-63
Encoding.UTF8, preamble: EF-BB-BF
Encoding.UTF8, payload: 61-62-63
```